# how the Prestashop code will flow?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I am new to prestashop. I wanted learn how the code will flow .

ex. how product are inserting in database ?
    how product data is fetching and displaying in store page  ?

please help me .

Answer (score 3):

you should open PrestaShop Product class.

you can get all product data using this:

```
$product = new Product($id_product);
```

if add a new product:

```
 $product = new Product();
```

**write all parameters like:**

```
$product->name = 'test'; 
$product->reference = '35GH'; 
$product->save();
```

If u print out product array you will see all parameters. GOod luck, have fun. And even lot of information in stackoverflow how to php add product and etc.

Comment: where can i get product class . ? can you tell me specific location

Comment: You can create a new product as I show and var_dump($product); to see all variables or open ps root dir / classes / Product.php

Comment: i need to get a product from database . i searched in product.php but i didn't get any related code

Comment: What about method getProducts? you can get all products and find your "PRODUCT"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on products like you want to add products,delete products,want some customization then first you have to create a new module. For that you have to create a new folder in that location with you module name

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name
```

Then after you have to create a file named your_module_name.php in that folder

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\your_module_name\your_module_name.php
```

After then you have to code in that file like:

your_module_name.php

class your_module_name extends Module
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'your_module_name';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'abc';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    //$this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('Your Module Name');
    $this->description = $this->l('This is the module for facilitate user to purchase particular product.');

    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

    if (!Configuration::get('your_module_name')) {
        $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
    }
}

public function install()
{
    if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {

        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
    }

    if (!parent::install()) 
    {

        return false;
    }
    $defaultsettings = $this->getDefaultSettings();
    $defaultsettings = serialize($defaultsettings);
    Configuration::updateValue('your_module_name', $defaultsettings);
    return true;
}

public function uninstall()
{
    if (!parent::uninstall()) {

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public function getContent()
{

    $output = null;
    $product = new Product($id_product);
    $product->name = 'test'; 
    $product->reference = '35GH'; 
    $product->save();
 }
```

Now in that getContent method you can perform operations on products.I hope it would help you.